# How to implement failover with MQTT brokers?

Tags: mqtt

I'm implementing a few devices and services with a fair bit of data running around my local network, with all publishers and most subscribers within the firewall.  Because it's easy, I'm starting with a CloudMQTT subscription, but ideally, I'd like that to be the primary (to service a couple of external clients), but if the internet goes down, I'd like an internal server to be a hot back up, with all publishing and, for internal clients, subscribe service.  I'm not sure if Bridging can help?

Is there anyway to implement this?  In my head, it's something like the way DNS works - you can have a local server, and to the extent it knows your answer, it can service it, but it has a place to go for further answers.

Answer (score 1):

Run a broker on each site and bridge it to the CloudMQTT instance. This way things can always communicate locally even if the internet is down